# Linux : How to replace words in files only on lines containing an expression

Tags: linux, sed, expression

I would like to replace in all the files contained in a directory (including subdirectories), the '/foo/' expression by '/foo/bar/' but only on lines that contain '.model'

ex :

```
import {....} from '../foo/toto.model' => import {....} from '../foo/bar/toto.model

import {....} from '../foo/toto.service' => unchanged
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that rather easily with `sed -i` and `find`. You will use `find` to locate all files below the chosen directory and then use `sed` to make the replacement in-place using the `-execdir` option to `find`, e.g.

```
find /some/path -type f -execdir sed -i "/model/s#/foo/#/foo/bar/#g" '{}' +
```

The regular expression `/model/s#/foo/#/foo/bar/#g` will only operate on lines containing `"model"` and then using alternate separators `'#'` for the normal substitute all occurrences of `"/foo/"` with `"/foo/bar/"` by supplying the `'g'` option at the end. (to replace only the first occurrence of `"/foo/"` remove the `'g'` from the end).

Let me know if you have further questions.